# WMV and MP4 support in TnyMice editor

Tags: video

I am using the latest version of TnyMice (4.1) in a custom CMS and find that it no longer supports WMV or MP4 video. Using the INSERT media produces an error "No video with supported format and Mimetype found".

The other option of using EMBED video expects the user to paste in the player code applicable for the video type. Somehow the latest version seems to only support Flash which is not recommended for this project.

I have seen an earlier version of TnyMice that added the player code automatically to suit the video type, and wonder what happened to that option because that would have been ideal.

Documentation claims that for WMV the Windows Media Player code is added, but I don't see that happening in this new version. Just some html that doesn't work.

How can I support WMV and MPG in version 4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 4 has been optimised for Flash, especially for YouTube links. So if you want more varied support for other types of video then the simplest solution is to revert to an earlier version.

See a list of [older versions here](http://www.tinymce.com/download/older.php)

Version 3 provides the embedded player code that you are missing.